# RSS feeds not working

Tags: bug, status-declined, rss

I would like to mix https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/feeds with other RSS feeds for my website, so I put it through http://www.rssmix.com/

Unfortunately, none of the Buddhism questions appear in the feed. When I try entering https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/feeds as a single feed, nothing appears, all I get is this output from http://www.rssmix.com/u/7920441/rss.xml

[image]

Comment: Looking into it. I get a successful feed of new posts on *meta*, but I haven't tried main. Have you tested this on a different RSS reader?

Comment: @abbyhairboat I cannot find another RSS feed reader to plug it in. However when I plug http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/feeds into a browser it shows latest questions...

Comment: Ok, I posted it at feedburner, http://feeds.feedburner.com/RecentQuestions-BuddhismStackExchange and it shows recent questions

Comment: That's what I suspected. It sounds like the problem is somewhere between our feed and rssmix. Not sure there's anything we can do about that, but I'll certainly ask around.

Comment: @abbyhairboat Actually, I burned the Buddhism feed into feedburner, and used that feed to mix with my other feeds. Now it includes the Buddhism feed

Comment: Good workaround. I asked around here and as far as we can tell that is a bug with rssmix - everything is coming out fine on our end.